# Destructure values from interface, else destructure undefined

Tags: typescript

I am using TS 2.4.

I have a function which takes `IConcur` which is an interface defiend as:

```
interface IConcur = {
   value: boolean,
   type: number
}
```

I am using it as argument to function:

```
const doit = ({ value, type }: void | IConcur = {}) => {}
```

However this gives me error:

> [ts]
>   Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'void | IConcurrency'.
>     Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IConcurrency'.
>       Property 'numberValue' is missing in type '{}'. [2322]

If the argument is `undefined`, I want the values to get destructed as `undefined`. How can I get TS to accept this?

Comment: You can make properties optional or define argument type as `Partial<IConcur>`, also define argument as  `{ value, type }: Partial<IConcur> = {}`. (`void` not needed because it is already optional due to default value). [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20IConcur%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20boolean%2C%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20doit%20%3D%20(%7B%20value%2C%20type%20%7D%3A%20Partial%3CIConcur%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%3B).

Comment: Thanks @AlekseyL. It this doesnt feel accurate though bcause i need all or none but Ill try for now thanks!

Comment: @AlekseyL. I tried `const doit = ({ value, type }: IConcur | {} = {}) => { };` please notice the `Concur | {}` but this is not working either.

Answer (score 1):

The dirty way (works only without strict null checks): You have to explicitly state the undefined-ness of the members of `IConcur`:

```
const doit = ({ value, type }: IConcur = { value: undefined, type: undefined }) => {}
```

A cleaner way is to do the destructuring in the method body (at the expense of an extra line) or - even better - add a specific if-clause for the undefined-case (if that's feasible in your case):

```
// without if
const doit = (concur?: IConcur) => {
  const { value, type } = concur || { value: undefined, type: undefined };
}

// with if
const doit = (concur?: IConcur) => {
 if (concur === undefined) {
    // special case 
  } else {
    const { value, type } = concur;
    // default case
  }  
}
```

In my opinion the last way is the best one because it is easy to read and understand for most developers (the other ones are way more hacky).

Comment: There is also a variant of the first way which works with strict null checks, but IMHO it is too hacky to include it into the answer: `const doit = ({ value, type }: IConcur | Record<keyof IConcur, undefined> = { value: undefined, type: undefined }) => {}`. Technically it satifsfies the requirement of OP of either both values of the object or none, but it feels strange to explicitly allow to pass such an object as a parameter into the function

Comment: I think the `Record<keyof IConcur, undefined>` will work, will try. I couldn't do the first appraoch of `const doit = ({ value, type }: IConcur = { value: undefined, type: undefined }) => {}` because `value` and `type` if present in `IConcur` can never be `undefined`.